# Python: Printing characters from the first string that are not in the second string

Tags: python, string

firstStr: "abcdabcdabcdefgh"
secondStr: "cdefijklijkl"

I need the program to print the list of characters that are in the first string, but are absent in the second string. No character should be printed twice.

For this example, it should print: a,b,g,h

```
for letters in firstString: 
    if letters not in secondString[0:]: 
        print(letters, end = ",")
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: And have you tried `set(firstStr) - set(secondStr)`?

Comment: Also, I couldn't figure out a way to make the loop stop.  Say if I wanted to print something else with the solution, such as "These are your letters:"  it would print that the same amount of times.

Answer (score -1):

another way to solve this problem

```
firstStr = "abcdabcdabcdefgh"
secondStr = "cdefijklijkl"

result = list(set(firstStr) - set(secondStr))
print(result)
```

hope this helps,

here are some sites to learn python
1)https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/index.html
2)https://pythonschool.net/category/data-structures-algorithms.html